# Partitioning an image based on features

Tags: image-processing, image, partitions

I have an image that has various characters hand drawn in it, like numbers and letters. I'm trying to partition each character into it's own image so I can run it through `Classify[]` and identify them one at a time (since `TextRecognize[]` doesn't work well on individual characters). My images look like this:
[image]

That's a bunch of 1's for putting into `Classify[]`. So it should be pretty easy to partition each one, but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is. I tried adapting this example:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/AnalyzeSegmentedCellsInAnImage.html

but I couldn't get it to work.

```
characters = 
  SelectComponents[
   DeleteBorderComponents[Binarize[a, {0, .7}]], {"Area"}, 
   100 < #1 < 1000 &];

outlines = 
  ComponentMeasurements[
    ImageMultiply[a, characters], {"BoundingBox"}][[All, 2]];

Show[a, Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle @@ # & /@ outlines}]];
```

This just returns a slightly lighter version of the original image with no red anywhere.

Comment: Classify ? Are you implementing it ? You can post the code as it is related.

Comment: @Sektor, [Classify](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) is a new function in v10

Comment: @SimonWoods Yeah, he just did not specify .. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `ImageTrim` to extract the bounding boxes from the image.

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjN95.jpg"];

m = MorphologicalComponents@Binarize@ColorNegate@MinFilter[image, 1];   
m = SelectComponents[m, "Elongation", # > 0.8 &];    
c = ComponentMeasurements[{m, image}, "BoundingBox"];

ImageTrim[image, #] & /@ c[[All, 2]]
```

[image]

Comment: nice and short!